# Handling Python imports nicely across different git repos

Tags: python, git, python-import

Lets say I have two git repos, *A* and *B*, depending on each other, both of which are under constant change, so it makes no sense to build them into an installable python package.

So far I solved the imports by adding the corresponding absolute paths of the other repo to sys.path.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/path/to/B")
from package_B import function_B
```

But this gets rather cumbersome as for every different machine I checkout the code from, I need to adapt this path. Furthermore it messes up my commit diffs.

What is the correct way to handle these imports?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+what+is+editable+install

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. It augments the default search path for module imports, within python it shows up prepended to `sys.path`.

So on every machine you checkout your repositories, you only need to adapt your PYTHONPATH once, no need for any `sys.path.append`.